# Removing outliers by filtering values in R

Tags: r, outliers, facebook-prophet

i have a dataframe like this :

```
         ds        y
1   2015-12-31 35.59050
2   2016-01-01 28.75111
3   2016-01-04 25.53158
4   2016-01-06 17.75369
5   2016-01-07 29.01500
6   2016-01-08 29.22663
7   2016-01-09 29.05249
8   2016-01-10 27.54387
9   2016-01-11 28.05674
10  2016-01-12 29.00901
11  2016-01-13 31.66441
12  2016-01-14 29.18520
13  2016-01-15 29.79364
14  2016-01-16 30.07852
```

i'm trying to create a loop that remove the rows which values in the `'ds'` column are above 34 or below 26, because there is where my outliers are:

```
for (i in grupo$y){if (i < 26) {grupo$y[i] = NA}}
```

i tried this to remove those below 26, i don't get any errors, but those rows won't go.

Any suggestions about how to remove those outliers??

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `grupo <- grupo[grupo$y<=34 & grupo$y>=26,]`?

Comment: No need for looping, use boolean indexing as above comment ^ shows.

Comment: thank you Andrew, that solution also worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
filter(y >= 26 & y <= 34)

       ds        y
1  2016-01-01 28.75111
2  2016-01-07 29.01500
3  2016-01-08 29.22663
4  2016-01-09 29.05249
5  2016-01-10 27.54387
6  2016-01-11 28.05674
7  2016-01-12 29.00901
8  2016-01-13 31.66441
9  2016-01-14 29.18520
10 2016-01-15 29.79364
11 2016-01-16 30.07852
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a base R solution and a `tidyverse` solution. Part of the strength of R is that for a problem such as this one, R's default of working across vectors means you often don't need a for loop. The issue is that in your loop, you're assigning values to `NA`. That doesn't actually get rid of those values, it just gives them the value `NA`.

In base R, you can use `subset` to get the rows or columns of a data frame that meet certain criteria:

```r
subset(grupo, y >= 26 & y <= 34)
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    ds             y
#>    <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 2016-01-01  28.8
#>  2 2016-01-07  29.0
#>  3 2016-01-08  29.2
#>  4 2016-01-09  29.1
#>  5 2016-01-10  27.5
#>  6 2016-01-11  28.1
#>  7 2016-01-12  29.0
#>  8 2016-01-13  31.7
#>  9 2016-01-14  29.2
#> 10 2016-01-15  29.8
#> 11 2016-01-16  30.1
```

Or using `dplyr` functions, you can filter your data similarly, and make use of `dplyr::between`. `between(y, 26, 34)` is a shorthand for `y >= 26 & y <= 34`.

```r
library(dplyr)

grupo %>%
  filter(between(y, 26, 34))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 2
#>    ds             y
#>    <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 2016-01-01  28.8
#>  2 2016-01-07  29.0
#>  3 2016-01-08  29.2
#>  4 2016-01-09  29.1
#>  5 2016-01-10  27.5
#>  6 2016-01-11  28.1
#>  7 2016-01-12  29.0
#>  8 2016-01-13  31.7
#>  9 2016-01-14  29.2
#> 10 2016-01-15  29.8
#> 11 2016-01-16  30.1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your very complete solution Camille, it works just fine, and helped to understand better the use of these functionalities in R. :D